# JetPack Compose accompanist Pager lerp not found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm learning accompanist pager and I want to set effect on the pager.

I want to use the lerp method like the document

```
Modifier.graphicsLayer {
    // Calculate the absolute offset for the current page from the
    // scroll position. We use the absolute value which allows us 
    // to mirror any effects for both directions
    val pageOffset = 
        calculateCurrentOffsetForPage(page).absoluteValue

    // We animate the scaleX + scaleY, between 85% and 100%
    lerp(
      start = 0.85f,
      stop = 1f,
      fraction = 1f - pageOffset.coerceIn(0f, 1f)).also { scale ->
        scaleX = scale
        scaleY = scale
      }

    // We animate the alpha, between 50% and 100%
    alpha = lerp(
      start = 0.5f,
      stop = 1f,
      fraction = 1f - pageOffset.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                                )
```

but I can't find the right import for the `lerp` method for animating the scale like documentation.
any suggestions are welcome

Comment: have you tried `import androidx.compose.ui.util.lerp`?

Comment: @MR3YY yes, but I couldnt find that

Comment: how you couldn't find it? do you mean AS isn't able to resolve it?

Comment: @MR3YY there is no `androidx.compose.ui.util`

Comment: maybe google isn't publishing `:ui-util` artifact. but anyway as a workaround it is super easy to make a `lerp` function without depending on extra dependency,
Copy the function body from: main:compose/ui/ui-util/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/util/MathHelpers.kt;l=24?q=lerp&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose

Comment: @MR3YY from where ?

Comment: the given link: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui-util/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/util/MathHelpers.kt;l=24?q=lerp&sq=&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose%2F

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I faced this issue. The issue solved after add this dependency:

*implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-util:$compose_version"*